# To use AIC and BIC to select models the data used must be normally distributed?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, aic

I'm studying AR(p) and ARMA models and when I was studying about information criterion I couldn't understand if my data needs to be normally distributed or not?

Is it a pre-requisite, to have normally distributed data?

Comment: As a heads up, many assumptions in statistics about normality involve the normality of the error term, not of the data themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope definitely not. The AIC simply measures the goodness-of-fit of the model along with a penalty term for the number of parameters in the model (to discourage overfitting). The BIC includes a term that is the log of the number of data points.

Nowhere here is the distribution of your data assumed normal.

Comment: BIC **does** assume a distribution of your data: it approximates the marginal likelihood using a Laplacian approximation which leads to a Normal distribution.